# Ansible - remove old backup files

Tags: ansible

For several modules, Ansible has a `backup` option.

```yaml
- name: template a file w backup option
  template:
    src: my_file.j2
    dest: /tmp/
    backup: true
```

Each time Ansible runs, and there is a change for that file, Ansible creates a backup file in the respective folder. In the end, there will be many backup files.

**Q**: Is there an elegant Ansible solution to remove these backup files for which it placed the file/template? E.g. keep only the latest 3 backup files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can:

- Use the `find` module to generate a list of backup files
- Use the `sort` filter to sort them by modification time
- Use list slicing to select all but the last `<N>`
- Use the `file` module to delete old backups

So, something like:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - template:
        src: myfile.j2
        dest: ./myfile
        backup: true

    - find:
        paths: .
        patterns: "myfile.[0-9]*"
      register: files

    - file:
        path: "{{ item.path }}"
        state: absent
      loop: >-
        {{ (files.files|sort(attribute="mtime"))[:-2] }}
```

You can run this playbook in a loop to demonstrate it:

```
for i in {1..10}; do
  ansible-playbook -e iteration=$i playbook.yaml
done
```

You'll see that it only ever keeps the most recent two backups .

Comment: That looks actually quite neat. Thanks.